# Can't map to column names: ggplot2 geom_point graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data below

```
> x.row10
                                                      2003   2004   2005   2006   2007   2008   2009   2012
drift av bil                                         12770  12440  14910  12640  16230  16000  16260     NA
utemåltider                                           5700   6600   6050   7830   8870   7990   7580   9860
resor, hotell                                         5620   5820   7960   9600   8210   9390   9890     NA
möbler, inventarier, textilier , hushållsutrustning   8540  10840  13400   9450   9910  11860  10430  13040
hyra/avgift för hyres-/borätt (inkl garage)          43360  44020  45160  49430  45370  44090  48740     NA
köpta livsmedel                                      26420  27910  28160  29100  28310  33020  35910  33740
hushållstjänster                                      9490  11690  13770   8650   7250  10390  11490  17140
transport                                            27230  30810  28810  28410  30500  30390  29360  34890
bostad                                               67890  67250  71200  75210  71000  73490  74710  81820
fritid och kultur                                    34900  35860  43600  46770  43540  46160  45840  51000
totala utgifterna                                   215300 219870 241920 241060 229290 253590 255950 277260
```

I want to create a ggplot with the `colnames` mapped to the `x` variable and the `rownames` mapped to the `y` variable. Basically I just want to draw the data points of all the row-names for each years on a graph, respectively. This together with a colour aestethic factor legend that shows the different row-names.

My try

```
ggplot(x.row10, aes(x = colnames(x.row10), y = rownames(x.row10)) ) + geom_point()
```

But I get

> Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the
>   dataProblems:colnames(x.row10)

How can this be resolved?

Comment: Try making the row names the first column. Then melt the data frame. The rownames will be one variable, and the colnames will be the other.

Comment: extract row names to a variable and reshape your data.frame to long form using `melt` or `gather`

Comment: @PierreLafortune what do you mean with melting the data frame?

Comment: See @jeremycg's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, `ggplot` likes "long data", where each row is a measurement, rather than having them grouped up. To fix this, we can make your data long (or melted) using the package `tidyr`. You might want to take a look at dat2, as an example of "long" or "melted" data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat2 <- x.row10 %>% mutate(type = row.names(.)) %>%
                    gather(year, val, -type) %>%
                    mutate(year = extract_numeric(year))

ggplot(dat2, aes(x = year, y = val, colour = type)) + geom_line()
```

Here's the output:
[image]

As your data is hard to get in, here's what I used (NB there may be some differences, if you want an exact code, try adding a `dput(x.row10)` to your question)

```
structure(list(X2003 = c(12770L, 5700L, 5620L, 8540L, 43360L, 
26420L, 9490L, 27230L, 67890L, 34900L, 215300L), X2004 = c(12440L, 
6600L, 5820L, 10840L, 44020L, 27910L, 11690L, 30810L, 67250L, 
35860L, 219870L), X2005 = c(14910L, 6050L, 7960L, 13400L, 45160L, 
28160L, 13770L, 28810L, 71200L, 43600L, 241920L), X2006 = c(12640L, 
7830L, 9600L, 9450L, 49430L, 29100L, 8650L, 28410L, 75210L, 46770L, 
241060L), X2007 = c(16230L, 8870L, 8210L, 9910L, 45370L, 28310L, 
7250L, 30500L, 71000L, 43540L, 229290L), X2008 = c(16000L, 7990L, 
9390L, 11860L, 44090L, 33020L, 10390L, 30390L, 73490L, 46160L, 
253590L), X2009 = c(16260L, 7580L, 9890L, 10430L, 48740L, 35910L, 
11490L, 29360L, 74710L, 45840L, 255950L), X2012 = c(NA, 9860L, 
NA, 13040L, NA, 33740L, 17140L, 34890L, 81820L, 51000L, 277260L
)), .Names = c("X2003", "X2004", "X2005", "X2006", "X2007", "X2008", 
"X2009", "X2012"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("drift av bil", 
"utemåltider", "resor, hotell", "möbler, inventarier, textilier , hushållsutrustning", 
"hyra/avgift för hyres-/borätt (inkl garage)", "köpta livsmedel", 
"hushållstjänster", "transport", "bostad", "fritid och kultur", 
"totala utgifterna"))
```

Comment: Between the reshape package or the tidyr, which is more recommended (standard)?

Comment: `tidyr` is the newer version from the same author as `reshape2` and `reshape` - both are fine, but if you are learning from scratch, I'd recommend `tidyr` (some will disagree, or recommend `data.table`)

Comment: Side note: `dplyr` has a handy function `%>% add_rownames("type")`, which may be better readable than `mutate(type = row.names(.))`.